# can't stop a form inside a modal from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using [jquery custombox](http://dixso.github.io/custombox/) to create a modal, and inside it, I'm creating a form.
I want to submit the form via Ajax. I tried using `e.preventDefault();` but it still submits. I tried to submit the form without the modal and it worked fine. Any idea how to fix this ?

Here's a link to a jsFiddle file [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayman_Mohamed/mMF47/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that your jquery custombox clones or recreates the form which does not have the event handler registered.

Try event delegation [$.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("submit","#registering",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9M5Py/)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a `<input type="button" ..>` instead of `<input type="submit" ..>` and bind an onclick action either on the element or in your Javascript code.

Comment: It's the same problem. It seems that there is a problem with binding events to the elements on the modal

Comment: That's odd, I just tried changing the `type` from `submit` to `button` in your JSFiddle and it didn't submit the form.

Comment: It won't submit any way because button type doesn't submit the form. You may say that I can make it send the data via ajax then, but the problem was that I can't bind events to anything inside modal.